# Error installing egit plugin on eclipse neon using hiera

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, puppet, puppet-enterprise, hiera

I am trying to install **egit** plugin on eclipse neon which is installed in my puppet agent by using puppet module concept.

But when I am trying to install plugin it showing error as follows

> Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list eclipse-platform'
>   returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list Error:
>   /Stage[main]/Eclipse::Install::Package/Package[eclipse-platform]/ensure:
>   change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0
>   -e 0 -y list eclipse-platform' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list

my hiera data file is

```
---
eclipse::plugin::egit:
-
eclipse::plugin::egit: true
eclipse::plugin::egit::enable: true
```

my manifest is as follows

```
node p01vm2 {
eclipse::plugin::install::p2_director { 'org.eclipse.egit.feature.group': }
class {'eclipse::params':}
}
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a problem with your yum repo subscriptions. You should start troubleshooting from there.

Comment: i am using centos 6.5. I will update my yum repo is that helpful for me